# tx proposed using proposeTransaction do no appear on safe-ui

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am proposing txs using proposeTransaction() from SafeServiceClient. The transactionServiceUrl points to an endpoint where I have deployed transaction service for Arbitrum-Rinkeby.

Transactions proposed do not show on the safe-ui under Transactions Queue. Is this the expected behaviour? If yes, how can I propose txs from my react app that show up in Queue.

Note - Safe UI points to endpoint of an ec2 instance that hosts all 3 necessary service as outlined in safe-infrastructure GitHub repository. Plus, proposed transactions do show up in the following GET request - **AP_ENDPOINT/txs/api/v1/safes/0xB44667eEbc583E928881966C7D5e27Bd77073aB3/multisig-transactions/**

---

[UPDATE 1]
The proposed transactions show up in the Queue on Safe-ui, but with a delay of around 30 minutes. I am not sure how is this delay arising, given that proposed txs show up in the response of API request for **multisig-transactions** right away.
Any idea what am I missing here?

---

[UPDATE 2]
Seems like my hosted version of safe-ui is updating with delay of 20-30 minutes. For example, I executed one of the pending transactions and the transaction appeared to have been confirmed around 15 minutes back. But on the UI the same transaction is in *pending* mode.

Comment: Sound like a caching issue in the client gateway. Did you register the webhook in the tx service to invalidate the client gateway cache?

Comment: you meant executing - "python manage.py add_webhook --url=http://nginx:8000/cgw/v1/hook/update/some_random_token"

inside safe-infrastructure_txs-web_1 container?

Comment: Yes, you should also see the webhook in the admin interface of the transaction service. And I assume you did not change webhook token (so it is `some_random_token`)

Comment: Since you host it on aws it might be that you have to adjust the urls of the hook

Comment: Yup! I had missed that. Thanks :)